# Apply HSV filter in Core Image

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I want to set the V component (in the HSV color space) to a constant for all the pixels of a CIImage.

It is easy to imagine a solution that loops (using for) over each RGB pixels, converts (by hand?) to HSV, set the value and convert back to RGB.

But in OpenCV/Python, this is two lines (plus it uses SIMD processor instructions for processing speed).

So the question is: what is the Core Image way of doing that, and fast?

I am using Swift5 for an iOS (iPhone) application.

Comment: You'll need to write your own CIFilter to do this. It's not hard to do, but won't be 2 lines of code. If you do, though, it will likely execute on the GPU and be very fast.

Comment: To expand on @user1118321, you could create a fairly simple `CIColorKernel`, which processes a single source pixel to output a single output pixel. It (by default) will execute on the GPU and will be very fast - much faster that most anything *not* using CoreImage. If you want to "dynamically" change the V component, I strongly recommend foregoing `UIImageView` and go with a `MTKView` and MetalKit. (You also can still use a `GLKView` but it was deprecated as of iOS12.)

Comment: Thank you! I managed to make color kernel with Metal doing so. I had to write the HSV conversion logic by myself though (I could find nothing in the lib to do it)

Comment: Mind sharing the metal kernel to process in the HSV space?

Comment: I will check if I still have it. It might take a few days.